# 3rd party dependency tracking tool

Tags: .net, parsing, dependencies

I need to program a C# software that tracks all dependencies inside a .Net solution by parsing C# code. Dependencies such as database/tables/queries-vs-commands touched, web services and project dependencies, included projects/dll´s/nugets. This information is used to have an overview what dependencies are active/redundant within a solution. The program should later on also be able to parse PowerShell scripts and even Ruby to check for dependent resources.

My question is if there exists a 3rd party tool that does part or all of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the tool NDepend that parses dependencies between assemblies, namespaces, classes methods and fields of your Visual Studio Solution.

It comes with a [dependency graph](https://www.ndepend.com/docs/visual-studio-dependency-graph), a [dependency matrix](https://www.ndepend.com/docs/dependency-structure-matrix-dsm) and a code query language that can be used to [query dependencies](https://www.ndepend.com/docs/cqlinq-features#Dependencies).

However it doesn't parse yet Database dependencies.